# Apache not serving php files

Tags: php, macos, apache

So I'm trying to get my LAMP stack to work in my Macbook. I've apache setup but PHP is not working. I've installed `php55` with Brew and loaded the module in my `httpd.conf` file like this:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php55/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

I've checked if the `libphp5.so` was at the location the module is pointing and it was there.

If I check my apache error.log I get the following message:

```
 [Sat Apr 23 21:36:59.307093 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7231] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
 [Sat Apr 23 21:36:59.358254 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 7231] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
 [Sat Apr 23 21:36:59.360623 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7231] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) LibreSSL/2.2.6 PHP/5.5.34 configured -- resuming normal operations
 [Sat Apr 23 21:36:59.360661 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7231] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

I'm missing something but I'm not quite sure what at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also update your Apache config to recognize `.php` extensions?

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

or

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I did indeed totally forgot the Filematch. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

add the following line to your httpd.conf:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

after apache restart everything should work